# Mapping of HTML5 permissions to Android Permissions

Tags: java, android, html, webkit

I was looking into [PermissionRequest.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/webkit/PermissionRequest.java) in AOSP. I was wondering what Android permissions those webkit permissions translate to. Camera and Audio are obvious, a little insight on "android.webkit.resource.PROTECTED_MEDIA_ID" and "android.webkit.resource.MIDI_SYSEX" would be great.

Thanks!